# IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; (Selenium)

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gecko

commenting out the configuration results in this crash:

```
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ gradle clean fatJar;java -jar build/libs/selenium-all.jar 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 17s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
Jul 09, 2017 3:03:39 PM net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium.Main main
INFO: init..
Jul 09, 2017 3:03:41 PM net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium.Scraper scrape
INFO: {webdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/bin/firefox, url=http://www.google.com, url2=file:///home/thufir/wget/foo.html}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium.Scraper.scrape(Scraper.java:24)
    at net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium.Main.run(Main.java:20)
    at net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium.Main.main(Main.java:15)
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$
```

How or where do I integrate [this](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver)?

```
{
    "capabilities": {
        "alwaysMatch": {
            "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                "binary": "/usr/local/firefox/bin/firefox",
                "args": ["--no-remote"],
                "prefs": {
                    "dom.ipc.processCount": 8
                },
                "log": {
                    "level": "trace"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even know what [that](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) means.

code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Scraper {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Scraper.class.getName());

    public Scraper() {
    }

    public void scrape(Properties p) {
        log.info(p.toString());

        String key = "webdriver.gecko.driver";
        String url = p.getProperty("url");
        String value = p.getProperty(key);
        // System.setProperty(key, value);
        // System.setProperties(p);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);
    }

}
```

Preferrably the configuration would be in a properties file.  What would the key/value pairs for that properties file?

Comment: the value for the webdriver.gecko.driver should be the path of the gecko wendriver and not the binary of the firefox. Can you show us your property file? You can download the gecko webdriver exe from here.,https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the following steps:

1. Download the latest geckodriver from **github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases**
2. Check the location of firefox on your machine.

   **On Mac Firefox is at location:** /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin

   **On Windows Firefox should be at the location:**  C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

   **Here is the code:**

   ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/monika/Downloads/geckodriver 2");  //the location of geckodriver on your machine
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
   options.setBinary("/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine
   options.addArguments("--no-remote");
   options.addPreference("dom.ipc.processCount",8);

   FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   ```